# Centrar items que estan Inline-Block

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un div llamado `container` y dentro de `container` iré cargando con `JS` varios `items`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que los items esten centrados pero uno al lado del otro, y cuando ya no haya espacio, pues creen otra fila. Como si estuvieran `display:inline-block;`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así, pero desde el centro. La forma que encontré de hacerlo es envolver todos los `item` en un elemento `<center> </center>` pero no quisiera usarlo

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="item"> 
       ...
   </div> 
   <div class="item"> 
       ...
   </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para lo que tú necesitas está la opción [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) que facilita mucho estas cosas.

A no ser que quieras hacer algo muy específico, una buena opción es usar algún framework que te facilite la vida con el CSS. A mi me gusta [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/).

Pongo un ejemplo con [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/). Cargo Bootstrap, y poniendo en el bloque que tú llamas `container` las clases `d-flex` (equivalente a `display: flex`) y `justify-content-center` (equivalente a `justify-content: center`) ya conseguirías lo que tú estás buscando:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Y si no quieres añadir Bootstrap, el modo de hacerlo es poner los estilos sobre el bloque de clase `container`:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div>Item 1</div> 
   <div>Item 2</div> 
   <div>Item 3</div> 
</div>
```

Espero que te pueda servir.